# Webdriver randomly creates addtional Firefox tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Sometimes when my web driver tests click on an element that executes a JavaScript function instead of carrying out the correct function the browser creates another tab with the JavaScript as the name of the title the test the falls over.

Why does this happen how can I stop it?

[image]

Comment: Is driver throwing an exception? What is present in those tabs?

Comment: The driver will throw an exception because what it is expecting to see on the page is not present, the tabs themselves do not cause the driver to crash. There is nothing present in those tabs. Could this be cause by running scripts directly off the page.

Comment: Is happens when I run a javascript

Comment: How do you mean, when you run a javascript? Can you post your code (html or webdriver) to show us the context?

Comment: I think it only happens when you click around on your machine will a test is running, what is happening is the focus is changing, if I leave the mouse and keyboard alone while the test runs I don't get the issue. However I am still investigating